# Remove nginx installed from source on Ubuntu

Tags: nginx, uninstall

I installed nginx from source (make && make install) on my Ubuntu 10.04 server. Now I want to uninstall it and install it again from the PPA repo.

How to uninstall nginx compiled from source?

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling packages installed from source is not an easy task. You can try `make uninstall` if is supported. If you still want to remove it, you can do it manually by removing every file installed by `make install`.

If your concern is about installing it again from Ubuntu repositories, you can just install it without worrying much about previous installation. Then, you can verify which version you are using.